# Script to rename photos with exif

Tags: bash, scripting, rename, photo, exif

i've a problem. I want to write a bash script to rename photos in different folders. 
Do you have any advice?

The input is:

- DSC3201.jpg
- DSC3202.jpg
- DSC3202-1.jpg
- ecc

The output i want is:

- 20141102_123259.jpg
- 20141102_124502.jpg
- 20141102_124502(1).jpg
- ecc

The format of output is: yearmounthday_hourminuteseconds.ext and when there is a photo modified (i put -1 in the last part of the name) i want an incremental number (1) or (2) ecc...

Sorry for my bad english, but i hope you understand my question. Thank you very much :))

Edit: Thanks for the reply!! I did this:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare dir_photo=$(ls $PWR | grep .jpg)

for N in $dir_photo do exiftool -d %Y%m%d_%H%M%S $N | awk -F': ' '/File Modification Date/{print $2}'  done
```

But if i want creation time and not the modification time what i have to change?

Edit 2: Sorry, the script running like a charm! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to get the date with your format :

```
$ exiftool -d %Y%m%d_%H%M%S image.png |
    awk -F': ' '/File Modification Date/{print $2}'
```

Output :

```
20140429_110955
```

Start beginning a script !

```
#!/bin/bash

dir_photo=(*.jpg)

for N in ${dir_photo[@]};  do
    date_str=$(
        exiftool -d %Y%m%d_%H%M%S $N |
        awk -F': ' '/File Modification Date/{print $2}'
    )
    print "$N $date_str"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.
To "posterity will" :D
I understand there are 2 ways to solve the problem:

With exiftool:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir_photo=(*.jpg)

for N in ${dir_photo[@]};  do
    date_str=$(
        exiftool -d %Y%m%d_%H%M%S $N |
        awk -F': ' '/File Modification Date/{print $2}'
    )
    print "$N $date_str"
done
```

Or with jhead:

```
jhead -n%Y%m%d_%H%M%S *.jpg
```

Choose what you prefer ;)